# What type of error is this Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: android, node.js

I am getting stuck at this error and not able to resolve this issue.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sagarkumar\AppData\Loca
>   l\Temp;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\8852-120drlh.jpg'

```
This is app.js file

var express  = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Configuration
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(connect.cookieParser());
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.bodyParser());

app.use(connect.json());
app.use(connect.urlencoded());

// Routes

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);


app.listen(port);
console.log('The App runs on port ' + port);
```

This is route.js file

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.end("Node-File-Upload");

});
/*
 app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

console.log(req.files.image.originalFilename);
console.log(req.files.image.path);
fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data){
var dirname = "sagar/";
var newPath = dirname + "/uploads/" +   req.files.image.originalFilename;
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    if(err){
    res.json({'response':"Error"});
    }else {
    res.json({'response':"Saved"});

}
}); 
});
*/

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

res.json({'response':"Saved"});

}
);
```

This is android code(client side) making json request(Only requesting part).
There is select button which is choosing image from gallery and upload button making request to nodejs server.

```
 upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      File f = new File(path);
      Future uploading = Ion.with(nodejs.this)
           .load("http://192.168.0.101:8080/upload")
           .setMultipartFile("image",f)
            .asString()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e,             Response<String> result) {
             try {
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result.getResult());
               } 
             catch (JSONException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 }
                 });
        }

    });
```

Comment: First you need to explain *where* you are getting this error.  If it is coming via logcat from the Android device, there's been a severe programming mistake, as nothing starting with a windows path like "C:\" has any relevance on Android.  If it is coming from your IDE or a tool running on a windows development machine, it could be a problem with a corrupt installation or project directory.  Or it could even be a "non-error" error, ie, a problem left over in unfinished code that shipped anyway, because the error doesn't stop things from working (sadly not unusual)

Answer (score 1):

The file C:\Users\sagarkumar\AppData\Loca l\Temp;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\8852-120drlh.jpg  doesn't exist.  It looks like you appended two filenames together.

Comment: I didn't get you and Not even getting this error. In my code neither I have updated any path nor I have mentioned.

Comment: ENOENT means Error No Entity.  In other words, no file.  The next part is the name of the file it was looking for.  In this case, that complicated broken path I copy pasted.

Comment: It doesn't care.  When you tell it to open a file, it opens a file.  Your code is what needs to know what the data means, to the OS a file is a file.

Comment: I had commented that path section as mentioned in code in routes file, it is still giving error.

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT = Error NO ENTity.

You have a problem with the file, maybe your path its wrong or the name of the file, but sure the problem is with your file.