# Error while uploading file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, file-upload, multer

I get the same error with this question: [What type of error is this Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804826/what-type-of-error-is-this-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open)

However, I get the same error for all type of folder I choose and I'm sure that I choose only one file. I gives this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'uploads/userPhoto-1501659100410'
```

Also, to be clear, my code:

Server.js

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end(err+" ");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

index.html

```
<form id        =  "uploadForm"
     enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
     action    =  "/api/photo"
     method    =  "post"
>
<input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Also I wonder if I can put the text inside the .js file into script and put both of them in the same jsp file. Because when I do that, I cannot get any output from that and I change the port of tomcat that I use as server in eclipse but it says

```
The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: app.post('/api/photo', upload.single('userPhoto'), function(req,res){ .. });

Comment: replace callback line with this one:-  
callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
then check again

Comment: @AmanGupta I got this error

app.post('/api/photo', upload.single('userPhoto'), function(req,res){
                              ^

TypeError: upload.single is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hazal/test/Server.js:18:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

Comment: @sagarpatel     callback(null, file.fieldname + '...
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

Comment: change to this: var upload =  multer({ storage : storage});

Comment: @AmanGupta TypeError: upload is not a function
   at Server.js:19:5
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
...

Comment: @AmanGupta
...
   at Function.process_params (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at expressInit (node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:33:5)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Comment: @AmanGupta
If I edit both of the code parts with the code parts prefered by you, then this is the error again
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'uploads/userPhoto-1501673749435'